# Django : NameError: name 'X' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I don't understand why ?

this is my project urls :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('account.urls'), name=account),
]
```

and this is my app urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpattern = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name=SignUp),
]
```

Error is : `NameError: name 'SignUp' is not defined`

Have you an idea what's the problem ?
Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Didn't you mean `name="SignUp"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `name=SignUp` and `name=account` which neither of them is defined in your code.

`name` parameter accepts a string so you either have to define a string variable or directly pass a string:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpattern = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name="SignUp"),
]
```

or

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

singup_name = "SignUp"

urlpattern = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name=singup_name),
]
```

Comment: if i do this i have an error : "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'account.urls' from ''path" does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import :(

Comment: That error has nothing to do with this problem. You might have a circular import problem

Answer (score 0):

> name=SignUp

here you are assigning value in Variable 'SignUp' into attribute but there's no variable SignUp declared.. maybe you want wrap it in quotes as string value such as this:

> name="SignUp"

Comment: if i do this i have an error : "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'account.urls' from ''path" does not appear to have any patterns in it. 
If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Answer (score 0):

in fact the solution was that I made a mistake in the urlpattern the real word was urlpatterns with an s